# Plot presence of feature in a 2d matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I have a dictionary (in python), where the keys are animal names, and the values are sets that contain gene names. Not all the animals have all the genes.
There are about 108 genes (of which I have a list) and 15 species. There are 28 genes common to all animals.

I would like to plot the presence of a gene in an animal for every animal  and gene. 
For example:

```
d = {'dog': {'tnfa', 'tlr1'}, 'cat': {'myd88', 'tnfa', 'map2k2'}}
```

The plot I'd like would look something like this:

```
        dog    cat
tnfa     x      x
myd88           x
tlr1     x
map2k2          x
```

It would be nice if I could group the animals with the most number of genes together too. But that's optional.

Do you have any suggestions for an approach I can make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
d = {'dog': {'tnfa', 'tlr1'}, 'cat': {'myd88', 'tnfa'}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')

df.stack().reset_index()\
  .drop('level_1',axis=1).assign(Value='x')\
  .set_index([0,'level_0'])['Value']\
  .unstack().rename_axis('gene')\
  .rename_axis('animal', 1)
```

Output:

```
animal   cat   dog
gene              
myd88      x  None
tlr1    None     x
tnfa       x     x
```

Comment: It runs with out an error, so that's great! How do you get the output though? `print(df)` doesn't work as expected.

Comment: You just need to assign that last line to df, `df = df.stack().reset_index()....`

Comment: I would propose wrapping the entire of your last line in brackets and ditching the explicit line breaks `\ ` to allow wrapping onto new lines, much more readable

Comment: This is amazing!

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas `crosstab` will get you the matrix you are looking for

```
d = {'dog': ['tnfa', 'tlr1'], 'cat': ['myd88', 'tnfa']}

#data munging
df = pd.DataFrame(d).stack()
df.index = df.index.droplevel(0)

#create and format crosstab
ct = pd.crosstab(df.index, df.values)
ct.index.name = "animal"
ct.columns.name= "gene"
ct = ct.replace([0, 1], ["" , "x"])
ct = ct.T

print(ct)
```

Results in

```
animal cat dog
gene          
myd88    x    
tlr1         x
tnfa     x   x
```

Not really sure about the grouping - do you mean by number of genes or common genes? Probably need some more examples as well for that one.

Comment: Ahh... Very interesting. I though pandas might come up, but I had no idea where to start. Thank you!

However, I'm getting an error, that I think is caused by the fact that not all the animals have the same number of genes:

`ValueError('arrays must all be same length')`

I will edit my question so that it's in the example.

Comment: Looks like Scott's answer is the one you want then!

Answer (score 1):

## A pure python solution:

Instead of using `pandas`, my solution just uses some simple `for-loops` and the `.ljust` method to print a neat table.

I am not too used to working with `dictionaries` in `python`, but using `.keys()` seemed the way to go. The code `loops` through each animal and gets that animal's genes. Then for each row so far in the table, if the first value of that row is in the genes, then just add an `'x'` to the end of that row to mark that this animal has that gene, also remove that gene so it doesn't create its own row at the end. Otherwise, if the first element of that row was not one of the animal's genes, then just append an empty string to fill that cell of the table.

Finally, for all the remaining genes, if they have not been removed from being already in the table, create a new `row` in the table with cells of: that gene, the number of animals already seen before (`['']*index`) and then finally an 'x' to show that the current animal does have that gene.

Finally, the last step is to inset a row at the beginning to simply have the animal names from the `dict`.

Here's the code:

```
d = {'dog': {'tnfa', 'tlr1'}, 'cat': {'myd88', 'tnfa', 'map2k2'}}
table = []
cellWidth = 0
for index, animal in enumerate(d.keys()):
   cellWidth = max(cellWidth, len(animal))
   genes = d[animal]
   for row in table:
      if row[0] in genes:
         row.append('x')
         genes.remove(row[0])
      else:
         row.append('')
   for gene in genes:
      cellWidth = max(cellWidth, len(gene))
      table.append([gene] + ['']*index + ['x'])

table.insert(0, [''] + list(d.keys()))
[print(''.join([c.ljust(cellWidth + 1) for c in r])) for r in table]
```

and the result is what is wanted:

```
        cat     dog
map2k2  x
tnfa    x       x
myd88   x
tlr1            x
```

#### Update:

I have added a `variable` : `cellWidth` which will store the greatest length animal or gene. To do this, the `max()` function is utilized to minimize code length. In the final `print`, the cells are printed with one extra space than the `max` so there is some room.

Comment: I really like this. But It gets problematic with multiple, long animal names. They get squashed together, and at the end of the row, the columns and their labels are out of alignment. I could probably get around this problem by adding a `\t` to each entry..

Comment: Never mind... I just needed to increase the justification

Comment: @Glubbdrubb the justification? [.ljust](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ljust) just takes a parameter to `pad` the string by. I will update the answer so this is calculated to be one more than the longest string...